# SCRIPT16389 error: remote xslt transform with parameter in ie

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Sorry guys.
I know this question has already been asked, but I was able to find only answers for xml files loaded locally.

I need to apply a stylesheet with one parameter to a xml document. Both files are retrieved from a remote server via XHR.

In firefox it works fine. I have problems only with IE.

This is my javascript code:

```
var data = loadXMLDoc("dataset_L190_2012.xml");
var styleSheet = loadXMLDoc("dataset_L190.xsl");;

// on document ready the xml gets displyed with no parameter set
// "datiL190" is the destination <div> for the parsed output
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#datiL190").append(getParsedXML(data, styleSheet));
});

// when user clicks button the xml document should get displayed with parameter set
function searchButtonClick(form) {
   $("#datiL190").empty();
   $("#datiL190").append(getParsedXML(data, styleSheet));
}

// remotelly load xml from supplyed address
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
   var xhttp = null ;
   if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
   } else {
     xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
   xhttp.send("");
   return xhttp.responseXML;
}

// "merges" xml and xsl document to get html output 
function getParsedXML(xmlDoc, xslDoc) {
   var result = null ;

   // $("#settore") is a text input that contains the parameter value
   var settore = $("#settore").val() ;

   // code for IE
   if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      // This would be OK if I had no parameters
      // result = xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc);

      // But I have just 1 parameter, so I need a free threaded document
      var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0");

      // and a xslt processor that uses the xslDoc to transform the xmlDoc
      var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");

      // xsl is empty: how do I fill it with xslDoc?
      xslt.stylesheet = xsl;

      // if I assign xslDoc to xslt.stylesheet directly I get this error:
      // SCRIPT16389: The XSL stylesheet document must be free threaded 
      // in order to be used with the XSLTemplate object.
      // xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;

      var xslproc = xslt.createProcessor();
      xslproc.input = xmlDoc;
      xslproc.addParameter("settore", settore);
      xslproc.transform();
      result = xslproc.output ;
   }
   // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
   else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
      var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
      xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "settore", settore);
      result = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
   }

   return result ;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can populate the `xsl` variable this way, and I have verified that it indeed works:

```
// But I have just 1 parameter, so I need a free threaded document
var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0");

// and a xslt processor that uses the xslDoc to transform the xmlDoc
var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");

xsl.async = false;
xsl.load("dataset_L190.xsl");

xslt.stylesheet = xsl;
```

Comment: Yes, it works.
Contrary to my belief, to all appearances the load method also load content from remote location and not only from local drive.
Thank you.

Comment: @user3005130 Great! Please mark this answer as accepted if your issue has been resolved. :)